# Neural network weird prediction

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I try to implement a neural network. I'm using backpropagation to compute the gradients. After obtaining the gradients, I multiply them by the learning rate and subtract them from the corresponding weights. (basically trying to apply gradient descent, please tell me if this is wrong).
So the first thing I tried after having the backpropagation and gradient descent ready, was to train a simple XOR classifier where the inputs can be (0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (1,1) and the corresponding outputs are 0, 1, 1, 0. So my neural network contains 2 input units, 1 output unit and one hidden layer with 3 units on it. When training it with a learning rate of 3.0 for >100 (even tried >5000), the cost drops until a specific point where it gets stuck, so it's remaining constant. The weights are randomly initialized each time I run the program, but it always gets stuck at the same specific cost. Anyways, after the training is finished I tried to run my neural network on any of the above inputs and the output is always 0.5000. I thought about changing the inputs and outputs so they are : (-1,-1), (1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, 1) and the outputs -1, 1, 1, -1. Now when trained with the same learning rate, the cost is dropping continuously, no matter the number of iterations but the results are still wrong, and they always tend to be very close to 0. I even tried to train it for an insane number of iterations and the results are the following: [ iterations: (20kk), inputs:(1, -1), output:(1.6667e-08) ] and also [iterations: (200kk), inputs:(1, -1), output:(1.6667e-09) ], also tried for inputs(1,1) and others, the output is also very close to 0. It seems like the output is always mean(min(y), max(y)), it doesn't matter in what form I provide the input/output. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, can someone please help?

Comment: provide the code, as your error is there.

Comment: @lejlot here's the code: https://github.com/cuvidk/yaann-api

Comment: Please 'edit' to include your code in the body of the question, as per [SO guidelines:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, please format your question so that it's easier to read. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many places where you might be wrong:

- check your gradients numerically
- you have to use nonlinear hidden units to learn XOR - do you have non-linear activation there?
- you need bias neuron, do you have one?

minor things that should not cause the mentioned problem, but worth fixing either way:

- do you have sigmoidal activation in the output node (as your network is a classifier)?
- do you train with cross-entropy cost (although this is minor problem)?

Comment: if you checked my code you saw that I'm using a vectorized implementation and i always add a column of ones at the activation matrix before multiplying it with the transpose of weights matrix, so yes i'm using a bias neuron. all the neurons use sigmoidal activation, and yes i use cross-entropy cost. as for non-linear hidden units, i'm afraid i don't understand what do you mean by that.

Comment: have you checked gradients numerically? Have you tried using more "typical" learning rate (like 1e-3) ? you should also set regularizationFactor=0 (I do not know what you currently use)

Comment: i just tried 1e-3 as learning rate, same results. i did not check the gradients numerically, i'm thinking about how to do that right now.  the current implementation makes it hard to do.

Comment: no it does not. Before update, you have x = x - learning_rate * gradient, simply here add numerical computation of the gradient and compare the two.

Comment: if I'm not messing it up, it seems like I'm incorrectly computing the gradient. with numerical gradient check i get the following output: 
        Numerical computed grads for theta 1 -> [0.0144   0.0132   0.0053 ; 0.0131   0.0098  -0.0030 ; -0.0022  -0.0031   0.0014]
        Analytical computed grads for theta 1 -> [0.0144  -0.0790  -0.1893 ; 0.0131   0.1244  -0.0331 ; -0.0022  -0.1428   0.2661]. I can observe that the first columns are computed correctly. I hope I'm not messing up the numerical computing.

Comment: ok, i'm clueless. It turned out I was computing the numerical gradients wrong. I fixed the bug and it seems that the numerical gradients are the same as the analytical ones. I have no idea what can be wrong.

Comment: i managed to fix it. it was a stupid typo mistake. thank you very much for your time. may i ask why did you say that the regularizationFactor should be 0?

Comment: on a second look, it seems that the regularizationTerm being set to 1 was also a problem. but why's that?

Comment: Because this is extremely simple problem and you do not need any regularization (this is why I told you to set it to 0). Higher the regularization - you penalize your network more for fitting to the training data. And here you want to fit to your data perfectly thus there is no point in penalization. In general, regularization is also added in completely different order of magnitude. "1" is huge regularization, 1e-2 would be more typical.

Comment: i understand, thank you.